# Linux shell scripts for commands to update multiple folders

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I have a script that I created that is just a list of commands (cp's, mkdir's, rm's, etc). What this does is basically update the contents of a bunch of folders with the contents of a source folder.

Right now I have about 15 folders to be modified with about 30 commands each. So when I need to add a folder, I need to add 30 more commands and specify that folder.

Is there a way in the script to create an array of folders to change and loop through it or something?

My script right now just contains basic commands that would normally be run in the command line, so nothing advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do something like this:

```
for x in "folder1" "folder2" "folder3"; do
  mkdir $x
  cp foobar $x
done
```

Better yet, use an array to hold the folder names, e.g.

```
arr=("folder1" "folder2" "folder3")

for x in ${arr[*]} do
  mkdir $x
  cp foobar $x
done
```

If you have specific names following a pattern, you can probably use a loop to generate that list of names automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach:

```
#!/bin/bash

# This function does all you clever stuff
# $1 contains the first parameter, $2 the second and so on
function my_cmds()
{
    echo $1
}

# You can loop over folders like this
for i in folder1 folder2 folder3
do
    # here we call a function with the string as parameter 
    my_cmds $i
done

# ... or like this
folders[0]="folder0"
folders[1]="folders1"
folders[2]="folders2"

for i in "${folders[@]}"
do
    my_cmds $i
done
```

a convenient way of initializing an entire array is the

```
array=( element1 element2 ... elementN )
```

notation.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to answers using `for` loops, but using a here document to store the list of folders. It's like having a data file embedded in the script.

```
while read -r folder <&3; do
    mkdir "$folder"
    # etc
done 3<<EOF
folder1
folder2
folder with space
EOF
```

I use file descriptor 3 for the here document in case you have commands in the body of the loop that attempt to read from standard input.